# AbstractTableModel doesnt return drive names

Tags: java, swing, file, abstracttablemodel

I am trying to create system file browser with starting in drive directory.

```
public class FileSystemTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements
    Constants {

private File currentDircetory;
private File[] files;

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
    switch (arg1) {
    case 0:
        return files[arg0].getName();
    case 1:
        return files[arg0].length();
    case 2:
        return new Date(files[arg0].lastModified());
    }
    return arg1;    
}
```

Setting values through

```
      public class Window {



static class MyFrame extends JFrame implements Constants {
    MyFrame() throws HeadlessException {


  FileSystemTableModel model = new FileSystemTableModel();
  model.setFiles(File.listRoots());
  JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Here is my result screen; How can i display drive names??

[The result](http://cs620227.vk.me/v620227202/2756/gZzCAZydrHU.jpg)

Comment: You'll want to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve you problem `files[arg0].toString()` for `case 0`

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
    switch (arg1) {
        case 0:
            return files[arg0].toString();
        case 1:
            return files[arg0].length();
        case 2:
            return new Date(files[arg0].lastModified());
    }
    return arg1;
}
```